# Gitignore a nested directory structure anywhere in my repository

Tags: git, gitignore

Pretty sure no one's asked about this exact pattern yet...

I have some (untracked) auto-generated config files that I'm trying to ignore:

```
?? PanDA/dp_ptu/cfg/cpp/
?? RCMB/cfg/cpp/
```

(The `cpp/` folder is auto-generated but there are other files inside `cfg/` that need to be committed.) So I've entered the following in my `.gitignore`:

```
cfg/cpp/
```

But it doesn't work. This does work:

```
*/*/cfg/cpp/
*/cfg/cpp/
```

Obviously that stinks because I need a new entry for every `cpp` directory. This also works:

```
cpp/
```

But I might want to have a `cpp` folder elsewhere in the repository so I'd really like to avoid doing this. Is there another way?

Comment: `**/*/cfg/cpp/` may work.

Comment: Hmmm... whatever implementation of `fnmatch` my shell/OS is using appears to ignore the `**`. Treats it the same as a single `*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
**/cfg/cpp/
```

works for me. Or you may try to put it into `.git/info/exclude`. Seems no other way if `**`is ignored in your environment.